# GitHub merge 2 folders with almost identical name

Tags: git, github

Before starting, I've searched and I haven't found any question like this one. Only similar stuff but not exactly as my problem.

I changed the name of a folder of my project from "assets" to "Assets" and pushed the commit to GitHub.

Suddenly, on GitHub I have 2 folders instead of one, some stuff is in the "Assets" and some in the "assets".

The weird thing is that if you pull everything into your computer, or just download zip from GitHub, you get only 1 folder named "Assets" with all the stuff in it.

How can I merge them into 1 folder in GitHub ?

Comment: When you "changed the name" did you use `git mv` or just `mv`? What operating system are you on (this matters if its filenames are case insensitive)? What does `git log --stat` say for that change? Is there anything in the `assets` folder on Github? It would be better to add this information to your question then to put it in the comments.

Comment: Both folders have files, some are on one folder some are on the other. When I changed the name of the folder I just did it with right click and rename on the folder. I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: You right clicked and renamed in what program? Windows Explorer? The Github application? Something else? And again, please add this information to the question using the [edit button](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36252142/edit). You'll get better answers if people don't have to read the comments to get all the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your probably experiencing a windows issue, where file names are case insensitive.

The easiest fix, if possible, would be rolling back, then using `git mv` to properly rename the folder.

Comment: Try using a posix os (linux, mac) to fix the mess.

Comment: Or backup, git rm (visible folder), commit, push, pull, readd backed up files, use git mv to rename. Do that on a separate branch, then merge it to master with --squash

Comment: So I need to use a case sensitive OS to fix that ?

Comment: Or try my second comment.

Comment: I manually moved all files through the git command line with git mv. Thanks for answering, this was the closest answer and the one that helped me the most !

Comment: I'm glad that I was helpfull, remember to git rm the now empty folder.

Comment: Looks like github removed it automatically because it contained no files. Do I still need to do a git rm, just in case ?

Comment: Cool then. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

You may have a couple solutions:

1) You covered the `git add Assets` commit but not the `git rm assets`

2) You have hidden files still appearing in the old assets folder (look for files that start with a dot)

3) You might be looking at a branch that still has the old assets folder.

If it isn't one of the solutions above you use this repo on GitHub:

https://github.com/tawman/git-unite

Comment: No hidden files in the folder. No branch used (everything pushed to master)

Comment: Looks like it is related to Windows being case insensitive and this problem will occur again.  Someone appears to have posted a solution on GitHub: https://github.com/tawman/git-unite